# Asp net core RC2. Как запустить MusicStore в debug mode

Tags: asp.net-core

Всем привет!
Пытаюсь перейти с RC1 -> RC2. Для изучения

- скачал MusicStore
- установил .NET Core SDK - .NET Core + CLI tools
- в папке с \MusicStore сделал dotnet restore
- в папке \MusicStore\src\MusicStore сделал dotnet build
- через dotnet run проект нормально запускается
  [image: через dotnet run проект нормально запускается]

Когда я открываю проект в VS2015, то вижу ошибки

```
unknown keyword platform
```

[image: Когда я открываю проект в VS2015, то вижу вот такие ошибки]

Соответственно скомпилировать проект не получается и запустить в debug не могу
Подскажите что нужно сделать?

```
E:\Develop\MusicStore\src\MusicStore>dotnet --info
.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-rc2-002543)

Product Information:
 Version:     1.0.0-rc2-002543
 Commit Sha:  38d0c28a1e

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.10240
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
```

Comment: VS 2015 Update 2?

Comment: Вопрос решился. Раньше времени начал переходить на RC2. В тот момент не была подготовлена оснастка для дебага. Сейчас установлена VS 2015 Update 3 и дебаг работает нормально